# CSS selector just for elements in submenu

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this menu with a slide down submenu:

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li class="menu-item current-menu-item">
    <a> whatever </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item current-menu-item">
      <a> whatever </a>
      <li class="menu-item current-menu-item">
      <a> whatever </a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Right now this is my CSS:

```
.sf-menu .current-menu-item a {
    background: blue url('images/diagonal.png') repeat;
}
```

This is changing all my menu items with class .current-menu-item, but I don't want to modify the ones inside the submenu.

How do I change the selector so it doesn't select LIs inside submenu? Or how do I make a selector to overwrite all LIs inside submenu with background:black?

I cannot modify the html, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the child selector `parent > child`.

```
.sf-menu > .current-menu-item > a {
    background: blue url('images/diagonal.png') repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to overwrite the rule for the submenu items.

So

```
.sf-menu .current-menu-item .sub-menu li a {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its actually quite simple:

```
.sf-menu .sub-menu  .current-menu-item a {
    background: black;
}
```

Or alternatively if you want to be more specific:

```
.sf-menu .current-menu-item .sub-menu .current-menu-item a {
    background: black;
}
```